# How to add a line between flex box rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a possibility to add separated lines between flex box rows?

Or any other solution for that?

Adding a border to all element it is not an option, as you can see in the example.

```css
.container{
  width:400px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    place-content: flex-start space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border: 1px solid #2662c3;
}

.item{
    flex-direction: row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    place-content: center flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
      padding: 16px;
    height: 65px;
    /* this is bab solution*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2662c3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

[Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qzvyow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use border on each `item`, though you need one of their pseudo element's, absolute positioned at the top, full width and set `overflow: hidden` on the `container`.

The downside with this is they need to top (or bottom) align or else the *"border line"* might break.

The upside, it will move dynamically with the items content, so one row can be higher than another.

Stack snippet

```css
.container{
    width:400px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    place-content: flex-start space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border: 1px solid #2662c3;
    overflow: hidden;              /*  added  */
}

.item{
    position: relative;            /*  added  */
    flex-direction: row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    place-content: center flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 16px;
    height: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;            /* compensate for border */
}

.item.higher{
    height: 95px;
}

.item::after{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -1px;
    width:100vw;
    border-top: 1px solid #2662c3;
}

.item{
    background: #eee;              /* for this demo only */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item higher"></div>
  <div class="item higher"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

---

The other way, were the border will adjust with different row heights, would be to either use a pseudo element on the `container`, and using `order`, position it between the 2 rows.

The downside with this is, there is only 2 pseudo and will only handle up to 3 rows.

Stack snippet

```css
.container{
    width:400px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    place-content: flex-start space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border: 1px solid #2662c3;
}

.item{
    flex-direction: row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    place-content: center flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 16px;
    height: 65px;
}

.container::before{
    content: ' ';
    width:100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #2662c3;
    order: 1;
}

.container .item:nth-child(n+3){
    order: 1;
}

.item.higher{
    height: 95px;
}
.item{
    background: #eee;              /* for this demo only */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item higher"></div>
  <div class="item higher"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

---

For more than 3 rows, one need to add an extra element, either combined with the pseudo or not, here shown when not.

Stack snippet

```css
.container{
    width:400px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    place-content: flex-start space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    border: 1px solid #2662c3;
}

.item{
    flex-direction: row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    place-content: center flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1 1 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 16px;
    height: 65px;
}

.container .border{
    width:100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #2662c3;
}

.container .border:nth-of-type(1){
    order: 1;
}
.container .item:nth-child(n+3){
    order: 2;
}

.container .border:nth-of-type(2){
    order: 3;
}
.container .item:nth-child(n+5){
    order: 4;
}

.container .border:nth-of-type(3){
    order: 5;
}
.container .item:nth-child(n+7){
    order: 6;
}

.item.higher{
    height: 95px;
}
.item{
    background: #eee;              /* for this demo only */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item higher"></div>
  <div class="item higher"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

  <span class="border"></span>
  <span class="border"></span>
  <span class="border"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a background coloration to create a line at the center:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid #2662c3;
  /*you border*/
  background: linear-gradient(#2662c3, #2662c3) center/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 16px;
  height: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```